# symfony : best way to set a user with a relationship

Tags: symfony, entity, relationship

I'm very new in development and symfony. I wonder me what's the best way to code this below.

I've 2 entities (user and account). There is a relation between them (create an account requiers a user).

I wonder me what is the best way to set the user in account entity (prepersist, controller, __construct) when I'm adding an new account ?

PREPERSIST

First, I didn't find anything to set the user with prepersit method. Is there a way ?

Something like that :

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function prePersist()
{
    $this->user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $this->updatedAt = new \Datetime("now");
    $this->isActive = false;
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
...

$user = new User();
$account = new Account();
$account->setUser($user);

...
```

CONSTRUCTOR

```
/* Entity account */    
...
public function __construct($user) 
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
...


/* Controller account */
...

$account = new Account($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser())

...
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code above, you don't need to hook into a doctrine event to accomplish what you want. You can create the association in the controller before persisting the Account object.

If you are using the Symfony security component, obtaining the user in the controller is as simple as `$this->getUser()`. You can inject User via the Account constructor method `__construct($user)` or a setter method `setUser($user)`. Although the constructor method is more efficient, either way is correct.

And to persist the Account object to your database from within the controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($account);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating Doctrine2 Listener / Subscriber and register it as a service, than listen to prePersist event of Account entity. You can inject any other needed services in listeners / subscribers.
All information you need can be found on: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html